# 'Malformed or invalid request' with clarifai api

Tags: clarifai

what is wrong with the following request for clarifai api-

```
import requests
image_url='https://samples.clarifai.com/food.jpg'
api='Key cb03ceba3c8842aeadd55dcb2f0be152'
headers = {
    'Authorization': api,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = '{"inputs": [{"data": {"image": {"url": image_url}}}]}'

url='https://api.clarifai.com/v2/models/bd367be194cf45149e75f01d59f77ba7/outputs'
response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.status_code, response.json())
```

i keep hitting this error-

```
400 {'status': {'code': 11102, 'description': 'Invalid request', 'details': 'Malformed or invalid request'}}
```

Comment: If one of the answers was helpful below, please remember to mark it to help others with similar questions!  Am also curious if the problem is still an issue...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to use:

`'{"inputs": [{"data": {"image": {"url": "' + image_url + '"}}}]}'`

Since the single quotes are creating a string, you can't just add in a variable directly, but need to concatenate it.  You were literally sending the text image_url and not the actual value of the variable image_url in that statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct the header as well to get a valid response

```
header = {'Authorization': 'Key '+ api_key ,"Content-Type": "application/json"}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert the data into JSON and json.dumps() will convert the data into JSON.

`data = {"inputs": [{"data": {"image": {"url": image_url}}}]}`

`json_data = json.dumps(data)`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; I solved it by converting the variable holding the image URL to a string. In your case, just make the following change:

data = '{"inputs": [{"data": {"image": {"url": image_url.tostring}}}]}'